# File or folder not found error, but the file exists

Tags: bash

I downloaded the android ADT bundle for Linux(my distro is Elementary OS), and after I unzipped it, I opened the folder `sdk/platform-tools` on terminal, and tried running the adb file. When running the `ls` command, it showed the file there. But when I type `./adb` or just `adb`, it shows that error on title. How could I fix that?
I've tried `chmod +x adb`

Screnshot:
[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show us how did you unzip it exactly. And `adb` will not work unless you install executable to one of your binary folders (`/bin` `/sbin` `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin`). `./adb` will work if you first will change directory (`cd`) to the one which contains the file. Otherwise try to execute it with full path like `/home/user/folder/adb`

Comment: I right-clicked the file and unzipped it. Also, I tried with the full path, same error.

Comment: Ok. What error? Could you type it here? Also if you can - make a screenshot, upload it to [https://imgur.com/](https://imgur.com/) and post link to it here.

Comment: I added the screenshot to the question. The language is portuguese, "Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado" = "File or folder not found".

Comment: OK. What about `./adb`?

Comment: Same. Also same error when using the absolute path.

Comment: OK. Can you execute commands `ls -la /home/lucastt/develop/android/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools` and `file /home/lucastt/develop/android/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools/adb` and post output to your question?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://imgur.com/4iHalfu.png

Comment: Very interesting. What will happen if you execute `/home/lucastt/develop/android/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices`?

Comment: The same error.

Comment: I am out of ideas. As last thing. Execute this `echo "#! /bin/bash" > ./adb_1 && echo "echo 'this is test'" >> ./adb_1 && chmod +x ./adb_1 && ./adb_1` and post output here. This command creates and executes script which outputs a string.

Comment: The output: http://i.imgur.com/5OCvsqs.png

Comment: The last picture proves you can execute files by calling them `./filename`. This means, I guess, when you call `./adb` you successfully execute it and output you see is coming from the `adb` file, not from the shell you call it from. I might be wrong, but there is no other explanation in my head about it.

Comment: Is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: There should be way. First, make sure you are doing everything as per instructions for ADB [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: The thing is that other executables aren't working either. In another folder (sdk/tools), the 'android' file runs.